# LiquiBase -- Any way to output change log sql to a file in 2.0.5?

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

Currently I am integrating Liquibase with my spring application using `liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase` bean

From java doc, tt is plausible to know there is an property `sqlOutputDir` to that bean class so that the sql can output to external file.

However, the feature seems not exist in latest 2.0.5.

So, the question is, what is the current `equivalent method or function` to output changeLog sql to external file, or the feature just have been totally removed forever?

Please give a hint, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent Java command for writing the SQL output is: `Liquibase#update(String, Writer)`. You can invoke this method in your Spring app by subclassing `SpringLiquibase` and overriding `afterPropertiesSet`. For example:

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibaseWriter();
    // ...
    return liquibase;
}

private static class SpringLiquibaseWriter extends SpringLiquibase {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws LiquibaseException {

        try (Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection()) {

            Liquibase liquibase = createLiquibase(connection);
            Writer writer; // ... get writer
            liquibase.update(getContexts(), writer);
            // ...

        } catch (LiquibaseException | SQLException e) {
            // handle
        }

        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

The call to `update(String,Writer)` will execute your changesets without actually updating the database. The call to `super.afterPropertiesSet` will actually perform the liquibase updates.

I did notice the [javadoc](http://www.liquibase.org/api/liquibase/spring/SpringLiquibase.html) you referred to in `SpringLiquibase` that mentions the `writeSqlFileEnabled` and `sqlOutputDir` properties. Apparently, these were removed but the javadoc was not updated (see [CORE-1104](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1104)). I'm not sure the reason that these options were removed or what the intended replacements are though. I've found that liquibase logging is a bit deficient, so this approach may be useful for logging (debugging) the liquibase SQL output.

Comment: Thank you, that's quite helpful. Hopefully liquibase can add the sql output in later release.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [updateSQL](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) command.

Comment: Thank you but that is the option when running batch file. I am working on a spring web application so calling command line is an weird option.

Comment: It can be called from ant and even from java (`liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main()`). But what do you plan to do with that generated from spring sql?