# Liquibase writing logs to stderr

Tags: java, liquibase, jboss6.x

I have Java project deployed to JBoss EAP 6.4 using Liquibase to upgrade the database on deployment. However all the Liquibase INFO logging is being sent to the stderr log. So it looks like errors.

Is there a way to configure the default logging stream?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The beast way (in my opinion) is to replace the built-in logging with the liquibase-slf4j logging interface. There are more details on how to do that in this question/answer and other answers linked here:

[How to get liquibase to log using slf4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880783/how-to-get-liquibase-to-log-using-slf4j)